# Triple pipe in C using pipe(), execlp() and dup()

Tags: c, linux, shell, process, pipe

Consider a new operator ‘|||’. It will take the output of the previous program and 
pass it on as input to three different programs. Give a program triplepipe.c for 
implementing the following command: ls –l | uniq ||| grep ^d, grep ^-, grep 
^p. Don't use popen() library call, system() library call, or temporary files.

I am using the following logic to solve first part of the question. 'ls -l' is done in child1, 'uniq' in child2 using child1's stdout as stdin and 'grep ^d' in parent using child2's stdout as stdin.  I am able to see the output.

But I don't know how to give the output from child2 to three separate grep satisfying the limitations set. Can anyone please help?

Comment: And where does the output of those 3 grep commands go? In bash, I'd solve this with `tee` and process substitutions

Comment: the output of them goes to stdout.

Answer (score 4):

Part of this assignment is basically to implement a 3-way `tee`. After setting up the pipes and child processes, you'll have to enter a loop which reads once and writes 3 times, until the read hits EOF.

In Linux there is also a `tee` syscall which isn't in your forbidden list. It would be perfect for this program, but it's fairly new, so there's a good chance your teacher doesn't know about it yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer. I will investigate and report back.

Comment: I tried using tee(). Since the input is coming from stdout and tee() needs length of the string to be passed as an argument, I am at a loss how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Quote "Pipes are just files "

Think you dup2'ed and currently have your data in a pipe  in one of the childs. Now just read from the pipe and  use Write System call and write to 3 different pipes.

From there you can process the data differently in 3 different processes

Think thats what you require ;)

Answer (score 0):

Attaching the answer to my question.

```
void main() {
    int p1[2]; // pipe between ls | uniq and grep
    int p2[2]; // pipt between ls and uniq
    int p3[2]; // pipt between ls and uniq
    int p4[2]; // pipt between ls and uniq
    int p5[2]; // pipt between ls and uniq
    char buff[200];
    char data[10 * 1024];
    int count;
    int teelen;
    pid_t ret;
    pid_t chd;

    pipe (p1);
    ret = fork();
    if (ret == 0) {
        pipe (p2);
        chd = fork();
        if (chd == 0) {
            close (1); // close stdout
            dup (p2[1]); // dup stdout to p2's out
            close (p2[0]); // close p2's in
            execlp ("ls", "ls", "-l", NULL); // execute command
            exit (0);
        }
        if (chd > 0) {
            close (0); // close stdin
            dup (p2[0]); // dup stdin to p2's in
            close (p2[1]); // close p2's out
            wait(NULL); // wait for child to finish
            close (1); // close stdout
            dup (p1[1]); // dup stdout to p1's out
            close (p1[0]); // close p1's in 
            execlp ("uniq", "uniq", NULL); // command
            exit (0);
        }
    }
    if (ret > 0) {
        close (0); // close stdin
        dup (p1[0]); // dup stdin to p1's in
        close(p1[1]);
        wait(NULL); // wait for child to complete
        memset (data, '\0', sizeof(data));
        do {
            memset(buff, '\0', sizeof(buff));
            count = read(p1[0], buff, 199);
            buff[count] = '\0';
            if (count == 0)
                break;
            strcat (data, buff);
        } while(1);
        pipe (p3);
        close(p1[0]);
        write (p3[1], data, sizeof (data));
        fsync(p3[1]);
        if (fork() == 0) {
            int c;
            close(0);
            dup(p3[0]);
            close(p3[1]);
            execlp ("grep", "grep", "-a", "^d", NULL);
            exit (0);
        }
        close(p3[1]);
        wait(NULL);
        pipe (p4);
        write (p4[1], data, sizeof (data));
        if (fork() == 0) {
            close(0);
            dup(p4[0]);
            close(p4[1]);
            execlp ("grep", "grep", "-a", "^-", NULL);
            exit (0);
        }
        close(p4[1]);
        wait(NULL);
        pipe (p5);
        write (p5[1], data, sizeof (data));
        if (fork() == 0) {
            close(0);
            dup(p5[0]);
            close(p5[1]);
            execlp ("grep", "grep", "-a", "^c", NULL);
            exit (0);
        }
        close(p5[1]);
        wait(NULL);
    }
    }
```

Comment: In a pipeline like this, you want all of the child processes executing at the same time.  You should not be calling wait() before any of your fork() calls here.  With what you have, you'll end up blocking on large files because the pipe buffers will fill up since there's nothing consuming the data at that point.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that. But the question demanded the results to be sequential. Hence the wait.

Comment: You're screwed if that's the case, unless you can guarantee the data is small enough that you can buffer it all in memory.  In any case, you'd still just want the waits between the three final children.  The ls -l and uniq need to run at the same time.

Comment: I will check it with a huge list of output. Thanks for the comment :)